# Pass a php variable to jquery as an argument

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, php-5.3

I have a question, how to pass val.idno after firm/editFirm/ so I need to do firm/editFirm/val.idno.Help me please guys.My jquery:

```
$.each(obj, function(i,val)
{
  $('#finalResult').text("Results");

  items.push($('<li/>').text(
    val.name_firm + "---" +
    val.idno+"---" +
    val.adresa+ "---" +
    val.cont_banca+ "---" +
    val.swit+ "---" +
    val.banc_name+"---"
  ).append("<a href='<?=base_url()."firm/editFirm/"?>'>Edit</a>")); 
});
$('#finalResult').append.apply($('#finalResult'), items);
```

Comment: Clarify your question please. It's too chaotic.

Comment: What is chaotic: I want to pass val.idno variable after editfirm
<a href='<?=base_url()."firm/editFirm/val.idno"?>

Comment: thats your question? concatenate `val.idno` to the string `firm/editFirm/`?

Comment: Where is your jQuery ? In a .php ? val.idno is a JS variable in your example, is that what you are referring to ? BTW, This code tries to concatenate a string in a PHP way, and its javascript...

Comment: I do not know if it's possible to send this jquery variable  to php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
var link = "<?php echo base_url()?>firm/editFirm/";
$.each(obj, function(i,val)
{
  $('#finalResult').text("Results");

  items.push($('<li/>').text(
    val.name_firm + "---" +
    val.idno+"---" +
    val.adresa+ "---" +
    val.cont_banca+ "---" +
    val.swit+ "---" +
    val.banc_name+"---"
  ).append("<a href='"link+val.idno"'>Edit</a>")); 
});
$('#finalResult').append.apply($('#finalResult'), items);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is the Javascript val.idno variable in your example, just do this

```
.append('<a href="firm/editFirm/'+val.idno+'">Edit</a>');
```

If you want to pass it to a PHP script at `firm/editFirm/`, do this :

```
.append('<a href="firm/editFirm/?myvar='+val.idno+'">Edit</a>');
```

Then in your php script, get with `$val = $_GET['myvar']`

Comment: But I have base_url()

Comment: well you need to be more precise in your question, it is very difficult for us to help you if you do not answer us. Again, where is this code ? in a .php file ?

Comment: If you need your base_url() in javascript, store it in a variable in your `<head>` in your .php. 
`<script type="text/javascript"> var BASE_URL = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" </script>`